# Error getting ddl for object, table doesnt exist, mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

After uninstalling and re-installing wamp server I cannot seem to open any of my tables for edit in mysql workbench. 
I get the error:

> "Error getting DDL for object" and "schema_name.table_name doesnt exist".

All the tables have their respective .frm and .ibd files in my mysql\mysql5.6.17\data directory, but everything just seems corrupted. Any solutions to this?

Comment: Have you re-installed the same version?

Comment: Why don't you export databases with mysqldump, then reinstall the server and after that you import the file with mysql -uroot -p < ....? .

Comment: Am not sure, is there a way to check? I re-installed it today, so there had to have been been new releases for the past year or so.

Comment: Ok, I just recreated my schema (wasen't really that big to begin with) and made a proper back up. Thanks for the help.